# What kinds of groups are there where every (nontrivial) element has prime order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, prime-numbers

What kinds of finite groups satisfy the condition that the orders of all their (nontrivial) elements are prime?
Is there a way to classify such groups?

Such groups definitely exist ($\mathbb{Z}^{n}_p$ (all its elements have prime order $p$ and this class of groups describes all abelian groups satisfying that condition (due to structure theorem for finite abelian groups)) and they can even be non-abelian (Discrete Heisenberg Group $H_{3}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ (all all its elements have prime order $p$)). However, I do not know any other examples.

Moreover, I failed even to make out, if the orders of each element of the group should be equal, or there is a group, satisfying both that condition and the condition, that there exist two its elements with distinct prime orders.
All I know, is that if such a group exists, it has to be non-abelian (as any finite abelian group with two elements of distinct prime orders $p$ and $q$ has an element of order $pq$ and $pq$ is not prime)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can take a look at the paper *[Classification of Finite Groups with all Elements of Prime Order](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2047414)* by Marian Deaconescu, which seems to definitively solve your problem. The answer is apparently that for such a group $G$, we must have one of the following:

1. $G$ is a $p$-group of exponent $p$
2. $G$ is a non-nilpotent group of order $p^aq$
3. $G\cong A_5$